# how can i share my web front page on social network site

Tags: gwt

In my api I have some buttons and I want when a user click on perticular button my web front page would be share on SNS like (FB,G+ etc).

```
googlePlusshare.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(final ClickEvent clickEvent) {
                    Window.open("https://plus.google.com/share?url=www.example.com","_blank","");

            }
       });
```

using the following code only link are sharing, whereas i want my front page share like a post and web page show like a imge. How  google choose image during sharing 
please help

Comment: why have you used `https:` two times?

Comment: Reading fast G+ Share API I did not find a way to post content (only the url in your way if you do not want G+ Button). Did you find a way ? Can you share a link or more info?

Comment: i am still searching for this

Comment: if i am using    Window.open("https://plus.google.com/share?url=www.facebook.com","_blank","");  it is sharing on g+ with image but other web page is not .

Answer (score 0):

google pluse and facebook support ogp(open graph protocol) and its provide some meta tag to share content information on facebook and g+

```
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content=""; />
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
```

if we are using simple meta tag like

```
<meta name="Keywords" content="">
<meta name="Description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="">
```

these help to search on google
if we try to share on g+ it only share HTML page title.

```
 NOTE : if you are using both page title and meta title then it ll read only page title, if you provide diffrent URL. whereas on same page url it wlii work...
```